# How to let screen reader to focus previous element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, accessibility, screen-readers

I'm trying to use the screen reader to get focus to focus back on the previous element.

Once the `Return button` is clicked, it will disappear and the `Submit button` will appear.
If the `Submit button` is clicked, it will disappear, and then the `Return button` will appear and the `focus` will be on the `Return button` itself.

I used the useRef to store the ref of the Return button. But the focus won't focus back on the Return Button after clicking the Submit button. I suspect it may be because the Return Button will unmount after it's clicked. So, even if I store that ref, that's the old one.

The following are code snippets:

https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-kirch-euwsbe

**ParentComp**

```
    import BucketItem from "./BucketItem";
    import OrderReturn from "./OrderReturn";
    import { useRef, useState } from "react";
    
    const ParentComp = () => {
      const bucketItemTitle = "Item: ABC";
      const returnButtonTitle = "information for return";
      const returnButtonText = "Return";
    
      const returnBtnRef = useRef(null);
      const lastReturnBtnRef = useRef(null);
    
      const [showBucketItem, setShowBucketItem] = useState(true);
      const [showOrderReturn, setShowOrderReturn] = useState(false);
    
      const handleClickReturnButton = () => {
        setShowBucketItem(false);
        setShowOrderReturn(true);
        if (returnBtnRef.current) {
          lastReturnBtnRef.current = returnBtnRef.current;
        }
      };
    
      const handleClickSubmitButton = () => {
        console.log("lastReturnBtnRef: ", lastReturnBtnRef);
        setShowBucketItem(true);
        setShowOrderReturn(false);
        lastReturnBtnRef.current.focus();
      };
    
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>Order Details Page</h1>
          {showBucketItem && (
            <BucketItem
              returnBtnRef={returnBtnRef}
              bucketItemTitle={bucketItemTitle}
              returnButtonTitle={returnButtonTitle}
              returnButtonText={returnButtonText}
              handleClickReturnButton={handleClickReturnButton}
            />
          )}
          {showOrderReturn && (
            <OrderReturn handleClickSubmitButton={handleClickSubmitButton} />
          )}
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default ParentComp;
```

**BucketItem Component**

```
    import ReturnButton from "./ReturnButton";
    
    const BucketItem = ({
      bucketItemTitle,
      returnButtonTitle,
      returnButtonText,
      handleClickReturnButton,
      returnBtnRef
    }) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <div>{bucketItemTitle}</div>
          <ReturnButton
            ref={returnBtnRef}
            returnButtonText={returnButtonText}
            returnButtonTitl={returnButtonTitle}
            handleClickReturnButton={handleClickReturnButton}
          />
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default BucketItem;
```

**ReturnButton Button**

```
    import { forwardRef } from "react";
    
    const ReturnButton = forwardRef(
      ({ returnButtonText, returnButtonTitle, handleClickReturnButton }, ref) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <div>{returnButtonTitle}</div>
            <button ref={ref} onClick={handleClickReturnButton}>
              {returnButtonText}
            </button>
          </div>
        );
      }
    );
    
    export default ReturnButton;
```

**SubmitButton Component**

```
    const SubmitButton = ({ handleClickSubmitButton }) => {
      const handleClick = () => {
        handleClickSubmitButton();
      };
      return (
        <div>
          <div>Click to Submit Return</div>
          <button onClick={handleClick}>Submit</button>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default SubmitButton;
```

**OrderReturn Component**

```
    import SubmitButton from "./SubmitButton";
    
    const OrderReturn = ({ handleClickSubmitButton }) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="return">Ship Back</label>
          <input type="radio" id="return" />
          <SubmitButton handleClickSubmitButton={handleClickSubmitButton} />
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default OrderReturn;
```

Comment: Hi! Please **reduce** the code in the question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: Re the CodeSandbox link you've added: The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Three reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Separately, again, please ***reduce*** the code to the **minimum** necessary to demonstrate the problem you're having.There's a large amount of extraneous code and markup in the question. I've tried to help anyway, but please read through the MRE link.

Answer (score 0):

Since we need up-to-date refs in order to focus the button, I think you need to do your focus in a `useEffect` (or `useLayoutEffect`) callback. Here's a simplified example:

```
const returnBtnRef = useRef(null);
const submitBtnRef = useRef(null);
const flagRef = useRef(false);

useEffect(() => {
    if (flagRef.current) {
        flagRef.current = false;
        returnBtnRef.current?.focus();
        submitBtnRef.current?.focus();
    }
}, [returnBtnRef.current, submitBtnRef.current, flagRef.current]);
```

And then in the code that makes the buttons appear or disappear, set `flagRef.current`:

```
flagRef.current = true;
```

The key parts of that are:

- Using a `useEffect` callback so we're dealing with up-to-date refs.
- Using a flag we store in a ref to know whether we want to do any focussing at all (since you don't want to do it any time the refs of the buttons changes, just when you mean to do it).

Live example:

```js
const { useState, useRef, useEffect } = React;

const Example = () => {
    const returnBtnRef = useRef(null);
    const submitBtnRef = useRef(null);
    const flagRef = useRef(false);
    const [showing, setShowing] = useState("submit");

    const toggleAndFocus = () => {
        flagRef.current = true;
        setShowing((showing) => (showing === "submit" ? "return" : "submit"));
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (flagRef.current) {
            flagRef.current = false;
            // You can use this:
            // returnBtnRef.current?.focus();
            // submitBtnRef.current?.focus();
            // ...but sadly Stack Snippets use such an old version of Babel, we can't in the snippet
            if (returnBtnRef.current) {
                returnBtnRef.current.focus();
            }
            if (submitBtnRef.current) {
                submitBtnRef.current.focus();
            }
        }
    }, [returnBtnRef.current, submitBtnRef.current, flagRef.current]);

    return (
        <div>
            {showing === "return" && (
                <button type="button" ref={returnBtnRef}>
                    Return
                </button>
            )}
            {showing === "submit" && (
                <button type="button" ref={submitBtnRef}>
                    Submit
                </button>
            )}
            <button type="button" onClick={toggleAndFocus}>
                Toggle And Focus
            </button>
        </div>
    );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Example />);
```

```css
button:focus {
    outline: 2px dashed grey;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```